# How to get "printf" messages written in NDK application?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, logging

if i am defining such function in java file

```
  /** 
   * Adds two integers, returning their sum
   */
  public native int add( int v1, int v2 );
```

so i need to code in c file

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_marakana_NativeLib_add
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint value1, jint value2) {

  printf("\n this is log messge \n");

        return (value1 + value2);
}
```

then from where this  printf will print it message ? 
In logcate i dont get it?

How can i debug any NDK application by putting log messages?

Comment: `printf(3)` will write to whatever is _standard output_ -- which may or may not exist in your environment. Better would be to find a supported logging mechanism.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

use `__android_log_print()` instead. You have to include header `<android/log.h>`

Sample Example. `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "\n this is log messge \n");`

You can also use format specifier like printf -

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "Need to print : %d %s",int_var, str_var);
```

Make sure you also link against the logging library, in your Android.mk file:

```
  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

Ohh.. forgot .. The output will be shown in `Logcat` with tag `LOG_TAG`

**Easy Approach**

Add the following lines to your common header file.

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "your-log-tag"

#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
// If you want you can add other log definition for info, warning etc
```

Now just call `LOGD("Hello world") or LOGE("Number = %d", any_int)` like `printf in c`.

Don't forget to include the common header file.

**Remove the logging**

If you define `LOGD(...)` empty, all logs will be gone. Just comment after `LOGD(...)`.

`#define LOGD(...) // __android_log..... rest of the code`

Comment: How do I remove the logging?

Comment: Just in case someone (e.g. me) using Android Studio (current mine is 0.8.11), you put ldLibs "log" inside 'ndk' tag. 
This solves undefined reference to '__android_log_print' issue.

Comment: As of Android Studio 1.4 Gradle 2.5 the LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog  has moved from Android.mk to build.gradle - use   'android.ndk {
        moduleName = "Your-jni"
        ldLibs += "log"
    }'  NOTE that .gradle syntax has changed in 2.5 (you need the '+=')

Comment: That doesn't help for Visual Studio Android debugging

Comment: This helped so long as I had this lib included in my build. This doc helped with that https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#add-ndk-api

Answer (score 18):

There is two options:

1) replace printf with __android_log_print. You can do this easily with define at beginning of code:

```
#define printf(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", __VA_ARGS__);
```

Of course this will require changing all source code that has printf.

2) redirect stdout and stderr to Android logcat (not sure if this will work on non-rooted device): http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd

Comment: when i use option 2 then after applying that 3 command when i run my application emulator just hang up in showing android bootanimation..

Answer (score 8):

not need to root device, acroding to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd, below can work prefectly.

```
$ adb shell 

$ su 

$ stop

$ setprop log.redirect-stdio true

$ start
```

done!

Comment: This method only works on android versions running dalvik (4.4 or earlier), ART versions (5.0 or later) dont support log.redirect-stdio.   Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=165602