# What is the 'export GST_DEBUG=<#>' equivalent for Android?

Tags: android, gstreamer

On Linux systems I've used 'export GST_DEBUG=<#>' to debug problems with a program's use of GStreamer.  I'm now working on Android and would like to do the same - see the GStreamer output included in the logcat output.

I have a Google Nexus 5 phone and I'm using the full_hammerhead_userdebug build.  I've seen the following suggested:

```
Add the following in JNI_OnLoad:
setenv("GST_DEBUG", "*:5", 1);
setenv("GST_DEBUG_NO_COLOR", "1", 1);
```

Unfortunately I'm trying to debug a C library, so I would prefer to set something in the environment to enable the debug output.  I tried to add the following lines to build.prop:

```
export GST_DEBUG=3
GST_DEBUG=3
log.redirect-stdio=true
```

That didn't work.  Either I'm not enabling GST_DEBUG properly or I'm not redirecting it properly.  Or I'm way off track and I should be doing something else.  How can I enable GST_DEBUG with Android?

P.S.  This question is similar to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876990/how-to-view-gstreamer-log-in-android), but that one didn't completely answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up going in another direction to solve this problem.  First I created my own GstLogFunction()

```
void gstAndroidLog(GstDebugCategory * category, 
                   GstDebugLevel      level, 
                   const gchar      * file, 
                   const gchar      * function, 
                   gint               line, 
                   GObject          * object, 
                   GstDebugMessage  * message, 
                   gpointer           data)
{
  if (level <= gst_debug_category_get_threshold (category))
  {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MY_APP", "%s,%s: %s",
                        file, function, gst_debug_message_get(message)); 
  }
}
```

Then after gst_init() is called, I set up the log levels.  If I want to see everything, I can set:

```
gst_debug_set_default_threshold( GST_LEVEL_DEBUG );
```

If I just want to see what is happening in a specific category, I can set:

```
gst_debug_set_threshold_for_name ("tcpclientsink", GST_LEVEL_LOG);
```

Then I just need to register the log function I created:

```
gst_debug_add_log_function(&gstAndroidLog, NULL);
```