# GStreamer pipeline playing, but no pad-added callback (only happens on Android, on Windows and Linux it works)

Tags: android, c++, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am using GStreamer (version 1.14.1) on Android and already have an implementation (in C++ code) that works on Windows and Linux.

I followed the Android tutorial from the GStreamer website to build my own `gstreamer-android.so` library to use in Android Studio. In my C++ code I added 
   `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE` and `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER` macros to register the static plugins. 
At runtime all GstElements can be created successfully. (I am using `gst_element_factory_make()` calls to do that.)

I build the pipeline like this:

```
GstCaps* video_caps = gst_caps_new_full(
    gst_structure_new("video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGBA", NULL),
    gst_structure_new("video/x-h264", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGBA", NULL),
    NULL);
g_object_set(m_app_sink, "emit-signals", TRUE, "caps", video_caps, NULL);
g_signal_connect(m_app_sink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(cb_new_sample), this);

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(m_pipeline), source, m_decoder, m_video_flip, m_queue, m_video_convert, m_app_sink, NULL);   
if (!gst_element_link_many(source, m_decoder, NULL)) {        
    gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
    return false;
}
if (!gst_element_link_many(m_video_flip, m_queue, m_video_convert, m_app_sink, NULL)) {
    gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
    return false;
}
g_signal_connect(m_decoder, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(cb_pad_added), this);
```

and later in the code start it with `gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);`

I am doing this with different elements as `source`: `filesrc`, `udpsrc`, and `videotestsrc`.

When I switch the pipeline into playing state, I expect to get the `pad-added` callback from the `decodebin` to be triggered and there I do the linking of the pad. All of this is already working on Windows and Linux for all 3 sources.

On Android, the callback only gets triggered for `videotestsrc`, but not if I use one of the other sources.

But what am I missing? Why would it work for videotestsrc but not with files and udp streams? (Permissions settings in the Android app are set correctly and static plugins are registered.)

Does someone know a sample implementation on Android where the pipeline is build manually and with the callbacks? (So far, I could only find examples with `playbin`, which I cannot use because I need to grab frames from the video stream.)

I am really out of ideas, why I don't get this callback. Any help and suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Update:**

After creating my own debug function (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550369/what-is-the-export-gst-debug-equivalent-for-android)), I can see that there is a problem with the encoder plugin for H.264.

```
2019-07-30 09:56:29.034 27551-27611/at.myapp.player E/GStreamer.cpp:: gstdecodebin2.c,gst_decode_bin_expose: error: no suitable plugins found:     
    Missing decoder: H.264 (Constrained Baseline Profile) (video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, codec_data=(buffer)0142c028ffe1001c6742c028db01e0089f97016a020202800000030080015f90078c197001000568ca8132c8, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1)
```

But I don't know how to solve it yet. I though by adding `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(openh264);` this should be there, shouldn't it?

Comment: Do you have a full minimal example? Do you properly wait after setting the pipeline into PLAYING state (run loop)?

Comment: Yes, after starting the pipeline it runs in a loop. 

I was finally able to get some log output by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550369/what-is-the-export-gst-debug-equivalent-for-android. 
And now I can see that there is in fact a problem with the plugins! I will update that in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it!

I added `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(videoparsersbad)` and now everything works for me! :)