# Redirecting stdout to console in Android app

Tags: android, c++, gradle

I am working on an Android project that has native code in `C/C++`. Earlier, for testing my native libraries, I used to create an executable for unit tests and test them via `GTest`. While running the executable, All the outputs of `std::cout` and `printf` are also printed in the console. But now I am creating an app to run unit tests to test my `JNI` functionality as well. When I run my app via the console by invoking the `./gradlew` command in a shell script, it sends the `stdout` data to `dev/null` and is not printed on the console. Is there a way to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` data to the console in real-time as the app runs?

Comment: What is "the ./gradlew command" exactly? Where is your [mre] ?

Comment: Are you talking about test on host side or on Android side? On Android all output to stdout should end op in `logcat`.

Comment: As i remember correctly, you have to use special NDK functions to output logs in native code. I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531050/redirect-stdout-to-logcat-in-android-ndk that have one answer which looks promising