# Demonstrating printf or __android_log_print Vulnerabilities With Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, printf

I am interested in demoing `printf` vulnerabilities via an NDK app. To be clear, I am aware that to log in the console we can use `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "Print : %d %s",someVal, someStr);`. I have tried it and I know it works. But I explicitly want to demo the vulnerabilities of `printf()`, specifically to use the `%n` specifier to write to a pointed location.

Is there a way to make `printf()` work to this effect or is it possible to achieve this via `__android_log_print()`? I attempted it with the `android/log.h` header but it didn't work.

I can get the app to crash by running something along the lines of `printf(%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s)`. But again, I can't manipulate pointers.

For general knowledge purposes, why is it that `printf()` doesn't work in the first place and how does `__android_log_print()` prevent these exploits?

Answer (score 5):

You do realize that Android is open source.

Starting with looking for `__android_log_print()`
and finding it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/master/liblog/logger_write.cpp

```
int __android_log_print(int prio, const char* tag, const char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  char buf[LOG_BUF_SIZE];
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  vsnprintf(buf, LOG_BUF_SIZE, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return __android_log_write(prio, tag, buf);
}
```

I eventually ended up looking at: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/master/libc/stdio/vfprintf.cpp

lines 453-454:

```
  case 'n':
    __fortify_fatal("%%n not allowed on Android");
```

Also referenced in the code is additional safety through FORTIFY which is described in the following blog post:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/fortify-in-android.html

Comment: What!? It's open source??

Comment: Can't tell if we both are being sarcastic. Regardless when you are trying to get into the deeper weeds of Android, you can read the source to see how it handles things.

Comment: Yeah I've been reading through some of the source trying to track stuff like this down. Guess I just didn't hit the right stuff. This explains to me why the ```__android_log_print()``` functions the way it does. So thank you for that. You'll have to forgive me but I'm still confused why ```printf()``` doesn't function at all.

Comment: `printf()` sends to console. In the context of Android there is no console. See: [How to get “printf” messages written in NDK application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10274920/295004) If you are trying to walk through the code [this post on printflike modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825270/printflike-modifier) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Android specifically does not support `%n` format specifiers because they're vulnerable.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/400b073ee38ecc2a38234261b221e3a7afc0498e/tests/stdio_test.cpp#328